# Preventing form from refreshing page Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

im quite bad at javascript, and i am trying to make a AJAX call, but i get my value from a form feild, and it just refreshes the page, cant even observe if the AJAX call is succesfull.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="subscribe-form" name="subscribe-form" onSubmit="return subscribe();">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
                         Subscribe
        </p>
        <div class="input-prepend input-append">
           <input name="subscribwEmail" class="span2" id="InputEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function subscribe() {
    var emailForm = $('#subscribwEmail').val();
    $('#subscribe-form').hide(); // hide email form
$('#subscribeDiv').prepend('<img id="process" src="http://www.mydomain.com/assets/img/process.gif" />')

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "../../actions/ajax-subscribe.php",
    data: {
        email: emailForm
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data[0] == 1) { // test if response was 1 or 2

            $('#process').hide(); // hide img

            $('#subscribeDiv').append('<p>Thank you for subscribing!</p>');
        } else {

            $('#process').hide(); // hide img

            $('#subscribeDiv').append('<p>There was an error subscribing the email.</p>');
        }
    }
})
```

};

ajax-subscribe.php

```
<?php
include ('phpfunctions.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die('ERROR WITH SQL CONNECTION CONTACT ADMIN');

$email = cleanString($con, $email);

$query = "INSERT INTO `subscribers` (`email`, `ip`) VALUES ('$email', '$ip');";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {

echo json_encode(1); // all ok inserted
} else {

echo json_encode(0); // failed
}

?>
```

Comment: [Here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is something you may want to look into. It's a plugin that takes care of ajax form submissions. It even allows for ajax file uploads via iframes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not cancel the click event so the form submits.

Add `return false;` to the end of your `subscribe` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **return false** from your **subscribe** method

Also you can validate the email, if it is invalid, you can stop sending subscribe by **return false**

You can also disable your submit button. (formObj comes with subscribe parameter)

```
        formObj.submit.disabled = true;
        formObj.submit.value = 'Log In...';
```

But you have to enable it if something goes wrong.